How do I fix the override content error on Chrome
I like the feature of chrome that allows overriding the content an API call returns. But it looks not working all the time, and I don't understand why is not working. Maybe someone here can help me with a clarification.

For some requests, when I want to save the data I get a small yellow triangle like the one in the attached screen capture with the explanation: "Changes to this file were not saved to the file system".
I have another API call who's response I did override and saved. See the second screenshot from the sources panel.

Both requests are from the same domain, API calls. I don't understand why the second one is not working - cannot be saved.
I tried to create in the destination folder a file called "file_id" and put the content I need inside it. But it didn't work, the browser didn't load the content from this file. The violet dot visibile on organization_db file name. (see the screen capture) was not present in the manualy added "file_id" file.
To resume, save didn't work for the second file.
I run Version 126.0.6478.183 (Official Build) (arm64) of Chrome, on Mac
I have a few questions, maybe partial responses can lead me (or other people, because are more people asking this question and no good response was provided so far)

Anyone has an idea how to fix this?
Is possible to manually link a saved file to an response (manually set the override)
Did I miss some settings/flags?


without an example link to reproduce the issue or very detailed knowledge of the tool it's hard to answer. Might be related to ajax, to special headers, to (no-)caching, there are many reasons thinkable.

Thanks David. I need someone that knows how this feature works - maybe someone from google that is involved in the development of this feature. For me looks like a bug in developer console.

I am encountering the same behavior and in my case it is because I have two endpoints, but they share a common path. The first endpoint is api/a and the second is api/a/b. Neither route has a file extension, so when saving to the file system, Chrome cannot save api/a/b because api/a is a file, not a folder.
Edit: I have also tried setting the overrides in the opposite order (api/a/b then api/a) but that also fails
